# Set C-plane (Construction plane) to a surface in Blender

Tags: axis

If you are familiar with the software Rhino 7, there's a feature that allows you to set the "construction plane" to the surface of an object.

**Doing this essentially provides a top-down view of the surface, and making any adjustments constrains it to the axis of that surface.**

Similar to how pressing 7 provides a top-down view, allowing you to make edits along the X and Y axis. Except I need to be able to do this along any surface, even diagonal ones.

Does Blender have a feature similar to this? Or is there a way to get around this issue?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is no option to align to a surface but you can align your view to the selected active face. Select a face from your mesh press Shift+Num7 to align from Top (check View > Align View menu for more options). If you want to roll around the selected face without changing your view plane you can center the view first pressing Home key then Shift+Num4 or Num6 to roll left or tight respectively (the options are in View > Navigation). The rotation angle is set to 15 degrees but can be changed in the Preferences > Navigation tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> you will have the top down view on the selected active face. Depending on your preference settings and if you were in orthographic or perspective view before doing this it is possible that the view on the face is perspective at first, you can press <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> to switch to orthographic view.

This not only works with top down view, but also front and side view by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and pressing the according numbers on the numpad. Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while pressing the numbers will get you the opposite view on the face, i.e. bottom, back, left view.

In this view, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> with <kbd>Numpad 4</kbd> will rotate the view counterclockwise in 15° steps, with <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> it rotates clockwise.

By the way, the decision what is "top" and what is "bottom" (other than the global alignment where the world coordinates are fixed) is made upon the face normal. Which means, the top down view will look at the face from the direction where the normal is pointing to, so if you have the *Face Orientation* overlay enabled, top down will be looking at the blue side of a face, bottom down at the red side.